# How can I get the predict future following value using Tensorflow LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

Thank you for reading. I'm not good at English.

I am wondering how to predict and get future time series data after model training. I would like to get the values after N steps.

So, I used the time series in the Tensorflow tutorial to practice predicting the model.

```
a = y_val[-look_back:] 
for i in range(N-step prediction): #predict a new value n times.
    tmp = model.predict(a.reshape(-1, look_back, num_feature)) #predicted value     
    a = a[1:] #remove first     
    a = np.append(a, tmp) #insert predicted value
```

The result predicted a value from -0.0000035 to -0.000005 very differently from -1.8 to -0.4 of the actual y value.as like below.

[image: 1]

How can I get the actual, right solution? or Is Tessorflow impossible to predict multiple steps?

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/96e0ba8d8c251046e89eae4bc5d40510)  (After the 25th line is my code.)

Answer (score 0):

If feel there is a small mistake in the code.

The line of code,

```
a = y_val[-look_back:]
```

should be replaced by

```
look_back = 20
x = x_val_uni
a = x[-look_back:]
a.shape
```

In other words, we should send X Values as Inputs to the Model for the Prediction, not the Y Values because, an **`LSTM`** expects its **`Input`** to be a `3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]`.

Please [Refer this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2) for more info about that.

However, we can compare it's predictions with Y Values, with the code,

```
y = y_val_uni[-20:]

plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(tmp)
plt.show()
```

Which would result in the plot shown below:

[image]

Please find the Complete Working Code in this [Google Colab Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/f1999818e9a35183f2c100087ce7dc7b/time_series_prediction.ipynb).